# Correctly close serial port inside a thread using C# / VB environment?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, serial-port

I am opening a serial port and then starting either a background thread or an EventHandler to process queued data from the serial port.

I enqueue the data and call event thread inside `SerialPort1_DataReceived` function.

```
rBuffer = SerialPort_GPS.ReadTo(Chr(13))
q.Enqueue(rBuffer)
Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf ProcessQueue))
```

After I make decision to not queue any more data (in ProcessQueue function), where should I properly close serial connection? Do I do it inside the thread?

My program is in VB, but I guess answers in C# would apply too.

Comment: You can close the serial port from any thread, but be prepared for serial port functions to start throwing exceptions.

Comment: Using Invoke() in the DataReceived event handler is a very bad idea.  This *will* cause deadlock when you call Close().  The port cannot close until the event handler stopped running, the event handler can't stop until the Invoke() call completes, the Invoke call can't complete until the UI thread goes idle again.  It isn't idle, it is stuck in Close().  Deadlock.  Use BeginInvoke() instead or just don't call Close at all.

Comment: Yes... I guess I was getting errors from DataReceiver when trying to close serial from inside the thread.

Comment: I would keep all serial port code inside the same class. When it's time to close the port, I would set a flag to true and then the serial port class would determine when is the best time to close the port and prevent all other read/write. I've something similar in the past and had two threads. One thread that took care of reading/writing and putting information in the queue. An other thread would take care of reading the queue and process the information.